# Envelope went out, but according to Docusign it says "Waiting for Others"

Tags: docusignapi

I ran a quick test with the RestAPI, using TemplateRoles instead of signers. Here is the code, pretty short:

```
EnvelopesApi api = new EnvelopesApi();
EnvelopeDefinition ed = new EnvelopeDefinition();
ed.EmailSubject = "here is the subject for this email";
ed.TemplateRoles = new List<TemplateRole>();
TemplateRole tr1 = new TemplateRole();
tr1.Name = "Kathy xxx";
tr1.Email = "kathyxxx@gmail.com";
tr1.RoutingOrder = "1";
tr1.RoleName = "Customer_SellerName";
tr1.ClientUserId = "1";
ed.TemplateRoles.Add(tr1);
ed.TemplateId = "3041bf29-a7a8-4903-89b1-577dec8fd591";
ed.Status = "sent";
EnvelopeSummary es = api.CreateEnvelope(AccountId, ed);
```

Here is the envelope definition and summary:

```
    envelope definition 
{
  "templateId": "3041bf29-a7a8-4903-89b1-577dec8fd591",
  "templateRoles": [
    {
      "email": "kathyxxx@gmail.com",
      "roleName": "Customer_SellerName",
      "name": "Kathy xxx",
      "clientUserId": "1",
      "routingOrder": "1"
    }
  ],
  "status": "sent",
  "emailSubject": "here is the subject for this email"
}
{
  "envelopeId": "7676b171-ccb7-4b40-821b-e1973ec99dfd",
  "uri": "/envelopes/7676b171-ccb7-4b40-821b-e1973ec99dfd",
  "statusDateTime": "2017-05-03T18:43:36.6770000Z",
  "status": "sent"
}
```

There is only one person getting the envelope, why does it say it is waiting for others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an envelope has at least one recipient who has yet to complete their action then it will show up under Waiting For Others in the Sender View.

From [Documentation](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-document-status)

> **Waiting for Others**. The document has at least one recipient who has yet to complete their action. The recipient status in the Document details shows whether the outstanding recipients need to sign (Needs to Sign) or view (Needs to View) your document.

Comment: Well, the person who was to receive this envelope never received it. It stayed up on Docusign's cloud.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work, but not sure why this worked. I commented out the ClientUserId and the envelope went out fine. Now I need to see what this ClientUserId property really does.

Comment: Another case of RTFM. It was right up under the definition for envelopeDefinition:  ClientUserId Specifies whether the recipient is embedded or remote. I should not have set this value at all since what I was doing was not embedded.

Comment: Glad you figured it out.